# Sweave does not open file dialog file.choose()

Tags: r, sweave

I work with R and Sweave. In order to select the most recent data file I try to open a file dialog with `file.choose()`. Simple as

```
filename <- file.choose()

tmp <- read.csv(filename)
```

Unfortunately the R/Sweave comes up with an error `Dateiauswahl abgebrochen` (german) that just says `File selection terminated`.

What's wrong?

Comment: presumably Sweave is switching R into non-interactive mode.  What are you trying to accomplish??

Comment: I have designed a flexible report (report.Rmw). The report is customized via a config file. I would like to give the user a opportunity to choose the config file.

Answer (score 0):

```
file.choose()
```

choose a file "interactively", which translate into "asking for user input".

In other words, R provides nothing to assign to filename

You may need:

```
list.files()
```

instead.

In your case:

```
filename <- list.files(pattern = '.*csv')
```